# URL changing with window.location.hash but not page

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application, window.location

I am trying to implement a single page application in knockout and at a point I am clicking a link to go back to a page. The URL is changing but it is still remaining on the same page. Only on refresh it is going to the required page.

I am using `window.location.hash = "#/home"` to set the link in the URL. 
Any idea what can be done so that the page actually changes according to the URL.

Comment: What are you currently doing to detect hash changes?

Comment: <a data-bind="click: function(){ $root.app.hash('home');}">Home</a>
This calls a function which changes the url

Answer (score 0):

Use event [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) like,

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
   // change your page content here
}
```